# How to dynamically choose a class to instantiate?

Tags: python, class, oop

I have three classes for `Dog`, `Bird`, and `Cat`.  Each is almost the same.  Without consolidating into one class of `Pet` - is it possible to choose from a list of pets, and then call that class?  I am getting an error right now:

```
oPet = randoType(random.choice(names))
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

My code:

```
    class Dog():
        """Dog class"""
    
        def __init__(self, name:str) -> None:
            """Initialize a dog"""
            self.name = name
    
        def speak(self):
            """Dog speaks"""
            return "bark, bark, bark"
    
        def getName(self):
            """Gets pet name"""
            return self.name
    
    ### OTHER CLASSES ALMOST SAME, NOT SHOWN

    names = [
    "Spencer",
    "Spike",
    "Stuart",
    "Tank",
    "Tanner"]
    
    petTypes = ['Dog', 'Cat', 'Bird'] 
    
    number_pets = random.randint(1,len(names))
    petSet = set()
    for x in range(1, number_pets):
        petSet.add(random.choice(names))

    listPets = list(petSet)
    oPets = [] 
    
    for x in range (1,6):
        randoType = random.choice(petTypes)
        oPet = randoType(random.choice(names))
        oPets.append(oPet)
```

Comment: Since you are studying OOP, shouldn't you practice inheritance?

Comment: Yes, it's on the #TODO list. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`randoType` is a string, not a class. Put the classes themselves, not their names, in `petTypes`.

```
petTypes = [Dog, Cat, Bird]
```